# Stuck on Combining Functions, D.R.Y

Tags: python, python-2.7, dry

I've been learning python for the last 10 mos. or so and I'm running programs which update objects in Salesforce. The fact that it's salesforce really doesn't matter.

What matters is that there are lots of little variations on the same procedure that I'm ending up with essentially the same function written but with slight modifications.

I'd like to consolidate as much as possible but I'm not sure exactly how.
I've put the code below with some descriptions

My questions revolve around how to make functions like this scalable. I'm having to repeat myself constantly but I'm not sure how to make this work.
Thanks!

```
def getSfdcAccounts(login,pw):
    '''
    This function queries Salesforce and pulls down a 
    list of accounts that meet the criteria of xyz, simple
    '''
    svc = beatbox.Client() 
    svc.login(login, pw)  
    qr = svc.query("select Id, Name, Website, type from Account where xyz")
    for rec in qr[sf.records:]:
        do something

def getSfdcAccounts2(login,pw):
    '''
    This function queries Salesforce and pulls down a 
    list of accounts that meet the criteria of xyz, zyx and abc, simple
    However, This is almost identical to the original function but has 
    significant variations. Should I be combining these?
    '''
    svc = beatbox.Client() 
    svc.login(login, pw)  
    qr = svc.query("select Id, BillingAddress, Name, Website, type from Account where xyz, zyx, abc")
    for rec in qr[sf.records:]:
        do something


def updateSfdcOjbect(lowin,pw,object,info):
    '''
    This function pushes a dictionary into Salesforce
    and updates the object based on the keys of the dict, simple
    '''
    svc = beatbox.Client() 
    svc.login(login, pw)  
    for i in info:

        update_dict = {
            'type': str(object),
            'Id':  info[0],
            'Website': info[1]
            'BillingAddress': info[2]
            'NumberOfEmployees':info[3]
            'Industry':info[4]
            }
        results2 = svc.update(update_dict)

def updateSfdcOjbect(lowin,pw,object,info):
    '''
    This function pushes a dictionary into Salesforce
    and updates the object based on the keys of the dict, simple
    However, the keys and values are slightly different. I want
    to update the Shipping Address, not Billing Address
    As well as the number of products rather than employees
    '''
    svc = beatbox.Client() 
    svc.login(login, pw)  
    for i in info:
        update_dict = {
            'type': str(object),
            'Id':  info[0],
            'Website': info[1]
            'ShippingAddress': info[2]
            'Nummber_of_Products__c':info[3]
            'Sic_Code__c':info[4]
            }
        results2 = svc.update(update_dict)
```

Comment: We have a separate website for questions of this type [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) :-)

Comment: Note that CR will expect to see full code, though; it's hard to answer in the abstract without seeing what the "significant variations" *actually are*.

Comment: And I feel that, you don't have to create `beatbox.Client()` in every function.

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle is to take the parts that are the same between functions
and put them into a common function, and then pass in the parts that are
different. So, using two of your functions as an example:

```
def getSfdcAccounts(login,pw):
    '''
    This function queries Salesforce and pulls down a 
    list of accounts that meet the criteria of xyz, simple
    '''
    svc = beatbox.Client() 
    svc.login(login, pw)  
    qr = svc.query("select Id, Name, Website, type from Account where xyz")
    for rec in qr[sf.records:]:
        do something

def getSfdcAccounts2(login,pw):
    '''
    This function queries Salesforce and pulls down a 
    list of accounts that meet the criteria of xyz, zyx and abc, simple
    However, This is almost identical to the original function but has 
    significant variations. Should I be combining these?
    '''
    svc = beatbox.Client() 
    svc.login(login, pw)  
    qr = svc.query("select Id, BillingAddress, Name, Website, type from Account where xyz, zyx, abc")
    for rec in qr[sf.records:]:
        do something
```

You could make a new function:

```
def getSfdcAccounts(login, pw, query):
    svc = beatbox.Client() 
    svc.login(login, pw)  
    qr = svc.query(query)
    for rec in qr[sf.records:]:
        do something
```

And then you call it with the different queries:

```
getSfdcAccounts(login, pw, "select Id, Name, Website, type from Account where xyz"):
getSfdcAccounts(login, pw, "select Id, BillingAddress, Name, Website, type from Account where xyz, zyx, abc"):
```

Beyond that, I agree with the what the others have said about putting this into a class and handling the connection setup there.

Answer (score 0):

These functions should all be declared as methods in the same class.  In the constructor of the class, you can can share the  beatbox setup:

```
self.svc = beatbox.Client() 
self.svc.login(login, pw)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class BeatboxClient(object):

  def __init__(self, login, pw):
    self.svc = beatbox.Client() 
    self.svc.login(login, pw)  

  def processAccounts(self, query):
    qr = self.svc.query(query)
    for rec in qr[sf.records:]:
      do something

  def updateSfdcOjbect(object, info):
    for i in info:
        update_dict = {
            'type': str(object),
            'Id':  info[0],
            'Website': info[1]
            'BillingAddress': info[2]
            'NumberOfEmployees':info[3]
            'Industry':info[4]
            }
        results2 = self.svc.update(update_dict)

  def updateSfdcOjbect(object, info):
    for i in info:
        update_dict = {
            'type': str(object),
            'Id':  info[0],
            'Website': info[1]
            'ShippingAddress': info[2]
            'Nummber_of_Products__c':info[3]
            'Sic_Code__c':info[4]
            }
        results2 = self.svc.update(update_dict)
```

Comment: Two of your methods have the same name and typo "Ojbect". Also, you forgot to add self to those methods.

Comment: Only idea matters in this case